# Can't Render an MVC View without a Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having issues rendering a view without a model associated to it.  I created a separate MVC project (the out of the box one in VS2013), created a view without a model and the view rendered with no problem.  Now for this project, I created a view with its associated controller and ActionResult method in that controller but unless I have a model associated in this view and pass one in it, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I didn't think a view had to have a model associated to it and passed in.  Here is what I have so far.

The view is called MainAddress and I'm not associating a model with it. All it has in it is the ViewBag.Title and a paragraph tag with "Test".

Here is the code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult MainAddress()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here is the view code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main Address"; 
}

<h1>Test</h1>
```

Is there a setting that is set somewhere making a model required or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: A model isn't required, but there may be code in your view that is assuming it exists; you'll need to post your view as well for completeness.

Comment: @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Main Address"; 
      } 

      <h1>Test</h1>

Comment: ...and this view is located in `~/Views/ControllerName/MainAddress`?

Comment: Hello danludwig, yes it is.

Comment: Is the view file named 'MainAddress.cshtml'? If so is there only these 4 lines of code only there?

Comment: Hi Venkat, yes that is the correct view name.  And those are the only lines.

Comment: Check the layout this view uses, does that expect a model?

Comment: Hello Dom.  Yep the layout does have a model.  In fact, I was talking to our architects about some other things and brought this up to him and he pointed out the layout having a view model as well as our view models needing to inherit that particular model as well.